# Openfire security (Firebug evil)

Tags: javascript, firebug, openfire

Let's say i develop web-based chat app (connection is maintained by strophe). What if one of my user which is connected to my app, open a firebug console and begin creating a new connection and broadcast message to another users. Is there a mechanism to handle this issue?

Comment: This is what server-side security and authentication is for.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot prevent this with client-side code.  As SLaks pointed out, you need to handle these situations server-side, where possible.

Also, nobody even needs Firebug to send these messages.  Just firing up a packet sniffer is plenty to get enough information to user your web services directly.  Easier yet with tools such as Fiddler, or the built-in browser tools for looking at network requests.